# Jekyll group_by first element of array

Tags: jekyll

How to use group_by filter with the first element of an array?

I use this like:
`{% assign categories = Object | group_by:"categories[0]" %}`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you give a little more code and explain what you're trying to do ?

Comment: Example:

```data:
{
- name: Example1
  categories:
  - category1
  - category2
- name: Example2
  categories:
  - category2
  - category3
}```

I want to group this data by the first element of array "categories", because when I use the whole array I get a few groups, like this:
- group 1: category1, category2, category3,
- group 2: category2, category3
- group 3: category1

and I want to get a few basic groups:
- group 1: category1,
- group 2: category2,
- group 3: category3